# Head function in eigen3 produces wrong result

Tags: eigen3

I want to get a subset of the vector s, the following code didn't give the right result. But if I write

```
    VectorXd e=s.head(svp)
```

e is right. Why the following code is wrong?  Thanks!

```
    Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd> svd(input, Eigen::ComputeThinU |
            Eigen::ComputeThinV);
    VectorXd s=svd.singularValues();
    int svp=5;
    s=s.head(svp);  //Wrong!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [`conservativeResize`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a3202c9faf8977ca71a9b53ef4e4cc70b) for tasks like this. The error is a type of aliasing; you're overwriting the data which you're reading from (although, in this case, I believe eigen will throw an explicit error for it)